# I need in a view to bring the value of T1.column1 only if the value of T1.column2 is equal to 1, if not print 'disable'

Tags: mysql, sql

I need in a view to bring the value of T1.column1 only if the value of T1.column2 is equal to 1, if not print 'disable'
What is the best function in SQL to do this in a view?

```
select T1.column1  from T1 where T1.column2='1';
```

Comment: Use CASE operator. `SELECT CASE WHENT1.column2 = 1 THEN T1.column1 ELSE 'disable' END AS column_name, ...`

Comment: A view does not "print", so your question is unclear.  What do you want `select * from the_view` to return?

Comment: Or the `IF()` function.

Comment: Thank you very much to all.
the Case function really solved my problem.
It was as follows: (CASE
            WHEN (`avu`.`is_stock_account`='1') THEN `avu`.`account_cc_id`
            ELSE 'DISABLE' 
            END) AS `SubContaBovespa`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case when` statement within your select statement as below:

```
 select (case when T1.column2='1' then T1.column1  else 'disabled' end) as column1 
from T1 ;
```